# Select nodes that has all relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have two kinds of nodes, `Person` and `Competency`. They are related by a `KNOWS` relationship. For example:

```
(:Person {id: 'thiago'})-[:KNOWS]->(:Competency {id: 'neo4j'})
```

How do I query this schema to find out all `Person` that knows all nodes of a set of `Competency`?

Suppose that I need to find every `Person` that knows "java" and "haskell" and I'm only interested in the nodes that knows **all** of the listed `Competency` nodes.

I've tried this query:

```
match (p:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(c:Competency) where c.id in ['java','haskell'] return p.id;
```

But I get back a list of all `Person` that knows either "java" or "haskell" and duplicated entries for those who knows both.

Adding a `count(c)` at the end of the query eliminates the duplicates:

```
match (p:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(c:Competency) where c.id in ['java','haskell'] return p.id, count(c);
```

Then, in this particular case, I can iterate the result and filter out results that the count is less than two to get the nodes I want.

I've found out that I could do it appending consecutive `match` clauses to keep filtering the nodes to get the result I want, in this case:

```
match (p:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(:Competency {id:'haskell'})
match (p)-[:KNOWS]->(:Competency {id:'java'})
return p.id;
```

Is this the only way to express this query? I mean, I need to create a query by concatenating strings? I'm looking for a solution to a fixed query with parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with ['java','haskell'] as skills
match (p:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(c:Competency) 
where c.id in skills 
with p.id, count(*) as c1 ,size(skills) as c2
where c1 = c2
return p.id
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do, is to count the number of all skills, then find the users that have the number of skill relationships equals to the skills count :

```
MATCH (n:Skill) WITH count(n) as skillMax
MATCH (u:Person)-[:HAS]->(s:Skill) 
WITH u, count(s) as skillsCount, skillMax
WHERE skillsCount = skillMax
RETURN u, skillsCount
```

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but this might do the trick:

```
match (p:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(c:Competency)
with p, collect(c.id) as cs
where all(x in ['java', 'haskell'] where x in cs)
return p.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
WITH ['java','haskell'] AS comp_col
MATCH (p:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(c:Competency)
WHERE c.name in comp_col
WITH comp_col
, p
, count(*) AS total
WHERE total = length(comp_col)
RETURN p.name, total
```

1. Put the competencies you want in a collection.
2. Match all the people that have either of those competencies
3. Get the count of compentencies by person where they have the same number as in the competency collection from the start

I think this will work for what you need, but if you are building these queries programatically the best performance you get might be with successive match clauses. Especially if you knew which competencies were most/least common when building your queries, you could order the matches such that the least common were first and the most common were last. I think that would chunk down to your desired persons the fastest.

It would be interesting to see what the plan analyzer in the sheel says about the different approaches.